# Comparing one ArrayList to another ArrayList using boolean method in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, boolean

I am trying to get a boolean method to return true or false on wether two `arrayLists` are equal to each other. The `arraysLists` are `array` and `array1`. The user inputs them. Right now here is the code that I thought would work:

```
public boolean equals(){
//if both are equal return true, else false
boolean test = false;
for(int i = 0; i < array1.size() && !test; i++){
    if(array1.get(i) == (array.get(i))){
        test = true;
    }       
}
return test;
  }
```

except even when all the `arrayLists` numbers match the other `arrayLists` numbers, it returns `false`.

Comment: btw, try array1.equals(array) and see how that goes!

Comment: If you have different numbers in the arrays, why it should return true? You are trying to consider the two ArrayLists equals if they have the same numbers even if the index is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to overwrite the equals method, as there is one already provided for lists that does exactly what you need.

If you insist of writing it yourself there is a simple error in your code.
Because you initialize test to be false, "&& !test" lets your loop exist right at the start.

The correct version would be:

```
public boolean equals(){
if(array.size()!=array1.size) return false; // test for different length
for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++){
    if(!array1.get(i).equals(array.get(i))){
        return false;
    }       
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is supposed to use `list.equals(otherList)`, given this is a homework assignment.

Comment: Well it would show the teacher that he is clever and knows the API :-)

Comment: Or it would show the teacher that he knows how to use eclipse's autocomplete ;D .

Comment: i put this into my code, initializing boolean test to be true and it still returned false when the arrays had the same amount of numbers, and the same specific numbers. Ex { 1 } and { 1 }

Comment: please use the code exactly as written here and report if you still got the problem. the test variable is not needed.

Comment: are u sure? u have return test at the end

Answer (score 0):

double equals (==) is dangerous. You are actually returning objects in your code up there, so you should definitely use equals() instead

Comment: == is dangerous, but he is comparing numbers (as he stated) therefore it is fine.

Comment: @Kevin, it is not fine because the numbers are `Integers` in an ArrayList, not `int`s. Therefore, he has to use the `equals()` method or it will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Think that you are only iterating one array. Think what can go wrong there. Also take a look at your control statement.

If you carefully follow the flux of your code you quickly will realize why is false.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your code to this:

```
public boolean equals(){
    if (array1.size() != array.size()) return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++){
        if(!array1.get(i).equals(array.get(i))){
            return false;
        }       
    }

    return true;
}
```

First off, you have to start with `test` being true and return false if you find something that isn't equal, because this clearly shows that the ArrayLists are not equal. You actually don't need the `test` variable at all, so I took it out. Just return false if you find something that isn't equal. If you don't find something that isn't equal, it will never return false and will just return true at the end. Second, you have to use the `equals()` method, because ArrayLists use the `Integer` class, not the `int` primitive so `==` will check if they are the same object, not if they are the same number. Lastly, to deal with comparing arrays of different sizes, you should compare their size and return false if they are not the same size, since there is no way they can be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You should just 'reverse' your method.  Assume the arrays are equal first.  It should then check on each iteration if the element differs.  If the element differs, then set a "not equal" flag.  In pseudo-codee

```
boolean different = false;
for (each element of array 1) {
    if (element != element of array 2) different = true
    break;
}
```